# error_log() do not take log_errors_max_len value

Tags: php, logging

A PHP 5.5 web app running in Apache does not take the value of `log_errors_max_len` when logging with `error_log()`.
The output is always trimmed at the same length if the message length is too large no matter what the value of `log_errors_max_len` is set to (0, 1024, 10000, ...).

I have run the following script (via the browser) and the output in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is allways a 8107 characters string.
The value displayed for `log_errors_max_len` is allways the correct one setted with `ini_set('log_errors_max_len', XXXX);`.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors_max_len',2000);

$msg = '';
$msg2 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $msg2 = $i.'_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $msg = $msg.substr($msg2, 0, 100);
}
error_log(print_r($msg, true), 0);
error_log(ini_get('log_errors_max_len'), 0);
?>
```

On the other side the same script running in CLI and logging to stderr displays allways the whole untrimmed string, no matter how small is the value of `log_erros_max_len`.

Following this reference [PHP Error Log Ignores log_errors_max_len Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229145/php-error-log-ignores-log-errors-max-len-setting) I get to a BUG report in PHP with Status "Not a bug" and with no more relevant info.

---

Ubuntu 14.04

Apache 2.4.7

PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using *Nginx* instead of *Apache*, and the same Ubuntu and PHP versions. Digging in the [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len) I found that the `log_errors_max_len` setting does not affect the `error_log()` function, and aparently theres is nothing to do about it.

Comment: Any idea how to increase or remove the length limit for messages sent by `error_log()`?